# Create a last visited list with Symfony & Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

I want to create a “last visited pages” list with Symfony and Twig.

For that purpose I wrote a history service which saves the last visited routes in the session.

But I just have the route name no alias for the user experience.

So the route `country_info` should hold a string like “Country Information”.
Is it possible to define a alias in the `routing.yml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to define route aliases in `routing.yml`. The routing system is not meant to do that.

If you have a fixed number of pages you could just read the session values in your Controller and translate each route name in order to print it with Twig later.

Supposing you are storing last visited pages routes in an array, you can try the following:

In your Controller action:

```
// Read session 
$page_routes = $session->get('last_visited_routes_array');

$output_array=array();

foreach ($page_routes as $route){
  // Translate route to name
  switch($route){
    case "country_info":
      $output_array['country_info'] = "Country Information";
    break;

    // ... Add more Cases here ...  

  }
}

// Return generated array so it can be used by Twig
return array('output_array' => $output_array);
```

In your Twig template:

```
{% for page_route, page_name in output_array %}
    <a href="{{ path('page_route') }}">{{page_name}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm aware of that possibility, but given that this project has about 50 routes it's not a very nice approach.